# Probability- conditional and binomial

Tags: probability

6) A hospital receives 1/5 of its ﬂu vaccine shipments from Company X and the remainder of its shipments from other companies. Each shipment contains a very large number of vaccine vials.
For Company X’s shipments, 10% of the vials are ineﬀective. For every other company, 2% of the vials are ineﬀective. The hospital tests 30 randomly selected vials from a shipment and ﬁnds that one vial is ineﬀective.
What is the probability that this shipment came from Company X?

How on earth am I supposed to come to the conclusion that this is a conditional probability? This may even seem like a even more stupid question but why is the probability that there is one ineffective vial equal to probability that it came from company x plus the probability that it came from another company?

10) A study is being conducted in which the health of two independent groups of ten policyholders is being monitored over a one-year period of time. Individual participants in the study drop out before the end of the study with probability 0.2 (independently of the other participants).
What is the probability that at least 9 participants complete the study in one of the two groups, but not in both groups?

Probability of dropping = .20

Probability of staying = .80

Probability that at least 9 complete the study in either group is equal to the probability:Of 9 +Of 8 completing + 7 completing ….+of 0 completing

$P[9]= b(9,10,.80)= {10 \choose 9} \times .80^9 \times .20^1= .2684$

$P[8]= b(8,10,.80= {10 \choose 8} \times .80^8 \times .20^2=$

$P[7]= b(7,10,.80)= {10 \choose 7} \times .80^7 \times .20^3=$

$P[6]= b(6,10,.80)= {10 \choose 6} \times .80^6 \times .20^4=$

$P[5]= b(5,10,.80)= {10 \choose 5} \times .80^5 \times .20^5=$

$P[4]= b(4.,10,.80)= {10 \choose 4} \times .80^4 \times .20^6$

$P[3]= b(3,10,.80)= {10 \choose 3} \times .80^3 \times .20^7=$

$P[2]=b(2,10,.80)= {10 \choose 2} \times .80^2 \times .20^8=$

$P[1]= {10 \choose 1} \times .80 \times .20^9=$

$P[0]= {10 \choose 0} \times 1 \times .20^10=$

${2 \choose 1} \times P{x \leq 9}= $
Since we want either group one or group 2 we have {2 \choose 1} ways either one of the two groups has at least 9 complete the study…This was the reasoning behind my answer. Yet why is this incorrect?

$P[N_i ≥ 9] = {10 \choose 9} \times (0.8)^9 (0.2) + {10 \choose 10} \times (0.8)^{10} = 0.3758 $

This tells me the probability that we have at least 9 complete the study from either group. Correct?

$P[N1 ≥ 9,N2 < 9] + P[N1 < 9,N2 ≥ 9] = 0.3758·(1−0.3758) + (1−0.3758)·0.3758=.469$

Then they take 1 minus this probability which gives the probability that at most 9 complete the study times the probability that at least 9 complete the study why?

Comment: For question 6. simply use Bayes theorem?

Answer (score 1):

(6.) Let $X$ be the event that the shipment came from company X and $\bar X$ that it came from another company. Let $N$ be the event that there was one ineffective vial. Then

> The hospital tests 30 randomly selected vials from a shipment and ﬁnds that one vial is ineffective. What is the probability that this shipment came from Company X?

can be rephrased as *Given $N$, what is the probability of $X$?* This implies a conditional probability. Then you must compute $P(X|N)$.

Next, you ask about $P(N)$. Notice that 
$$P(N) = P((N\cap X)\cup (N\cap \bar X)) = P(N\cap X)+P(N\cap \bar X)$$
since $N\cap X$ and $N\cap \bar X$ are disjoint. In plain words, either you got one ineffective vial and the shipment was from X, or you got one ineffective vial and the shipment was from some other company. You can't get one ineffective vial and have the shipment be from X and not X. This is called the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

(10.)

> Probability that at least 9 complete the study in either group is equal to the probability:Of 9 +Of 8 completing + 7 completing ….+of 0 completing

No. You are describing the probability that **at most** 9 people complete the study. If we call $N_i$ the number of people that complete the study in a particular group, then you want exactly $P(N_i\geq 9)$ like the solution described. I will let $p$ be $0.3758$, the value you provided. You were on the right track. $p$ is the probability of at least 9 members complete the study (success) for a particular group. We are interested in the chance that exactly one group does this. Notice that because the groups are independent, we can use the binomial distribution to find the desired probability with $n = 2$ and $p = 0.3758$. Then
$$P(\text{Exactly one group is successful}) = \binom{2}{1}(0.3758)^1(1-0.3758)^{2-1}\approx 0.469.$$

As provided, you can also alternatively label the groups and do
\begin{align*}
P(\text{Exactly one group is successful}) &= P((N_1\geq 9\cap N_2 <9)\cup (N_1<9 \cap N_2\geq 9))\\
&=P(N_1 \geq 9\cap N2 < 9) + P(N_1 < 9,N_2 \geq 9) \\
&= 0.3758\cdot(1-0.3758) + (1-0.3758)\cdot 0.3758\\
&\approx 0.469.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

> How on earth am I supposed to come to the conclusion that this is a conditional probability?

You seek a probability under a given condition.   Ie: the probability for the origin being company X given the sample was one ineffective among thirty.

> This may even seem like a even more stupid question but why is the probability that there is one ineffective vial equal to probability that it came from company x plus the probability that it came from another company?

That is called the Law of Total Probability: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B) &= \mathsf P(B\cap(A\cup A^\complement)) \\[1ex] &= \mathsf P(B\cap A)+\mathsf P(B\cap A^\complement) \\[1ex] &= \mathsf P(B\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\mid A^\complement)\mathsf P(A^\complement)\end{align}$$ After which, you apply Bayes' Rule $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid B) ~&= ~\dfrac{\mathsf P(B\mid A)\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(B\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\mid A^\complement)\mathsf P(A^\complement)} \end{align}$$

> This was the reasoning behind my answer. Yet why is this incorrect?

Your reasoning by symmetry is okay, however, you neglected the possibility that both groups might fail to have enough.

Further you are after the probability that one group succeeds while the other fails, to have enough.  $$\mathsf P((F_1\cup F_2)\setminus(F_1\cap F_2))~=~\mathsf P((F_1\cap F_2^\complement)\cup (F_1^\complement \cap F_2)) ~=~ 2 \,\mathsf P(F_\star)\,(1-\mathsf P(F_\star))$$

> Then they take 1 minus this probability which gives the probability that at most 9 complete the study times the probability that at least 9 complete the study why?

The rule of complements: The probability for an event and the probability for its complement sum to one.

Thus: $\mathsf P(F_\star^\complement)=1-\mathsf P(F_\star)$

In this case $\mathsf P(N_\star< 9)=1-\mathsf P(N_\star\geq 9)$ and it is much easier to find $\mathsf P(N_\star\geq 9)$ . $$\mathsf P(N_\star\geq 9) = \tbinom{10}9 0.8^90.2 + 0.8^{10}$$